# MySql orderBy and COUNT()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get a count of the number of times an item has been purchased. However, I also have a category table that is also being counted in my query, which of course is causing the wrong data. How can I count the rows I need in one table and only get those results?

**MySQL query**

```
    select 
    `inventory`.`on_sale`,
    `inventory`.`id`,
    `inventory`.`sku`,
    `inventory`.`name`,
    `inventory`.`price`,
    `inventory_categories`.`category`,
    `inventory`.`stock_quantity`,
    COUNT(orders_product.sku) as skuCount
from
    `inventory`
        left join
    `orders_product` ON `orders_product`.`sku` = `inventory`.`sku`
        left join
    `inventory_categories` ON `inventory`.`sku` = `inventory_categories`.`sku`
group by `inventory_categories`.`category`
order by `skuCount` desc
limit 10000
```

It is hard to show all my records but it's basically like this:

```
orders_product.sku = ORDER1234 & ORDER1234 & ORDER891010

inventory_categories.(id)category = (cat1)ORDER1234 & (cat1a)ORDER1234 & (cat1b)ORDER1234 & (cat2)ORDER891010
```

So in my table in my table it's showing skuCount = 5 & 2 respectively instead of the needed result of 2 & 1 respectively. If I do not have an order with  that inventory.id then it shows 0 which is correct but as soon as an order comes through it will count that order PLUS all the categories that equal that sku.

If I remove the inventory_categories from my join statement it works with no problems. However, it is needed in the query for record purposes.

Comment: just join a count that isn't getting the wrong results

Comment: Add an http://sqlfiddle.com/ it's hard to understand the tables and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following query:

```
SELECT i.on_sale, i.id, i.sku, i.name, i.price, ic.category, i.stock_quantity, 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM orders_product op
  WHERE op.sku = i.sku
) AS skuCount
FROM inventory i
LEFT JOIN inventory_categories ic ON i.sku = ic.sku
ORDER BY skuCount DESC
LIMIT 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.on_sale, a.id, a.sku,a.name,a.price, a.stock_Quantity, skucount, count(ic.category) as CatCount
FROM 
( SELECT 
    `inventory`.`on_sale`,
    `inventory`.`id`,
    `inventory`.`sku`,
    `inventory`.`name`,
    `inventory`.`price`,
    `inventory`.`stock_quantity`,
    COUNT(orders_product.sku) as skuCount
  FROM `inventory`
  LEFT JOIN `orders_product` 
    ON `orders_product`.`sku` = `inventory`.`sku`
  GROUP BY `inventory`.`on_sale`, `inventory`.`id`,
    `inventory`.`sku`, `inventory`.`name`,
    `inventory`.`price`, `inventory`.`stock_quantity`) A
LEFT JOIN  `inventory_categories` IC
  ON `inventory`.`sku` = `inventory_categories`.`sku`
GROUP BY A.on_sale, a.id, a.sku,a.name,a.price, a.stock_Quantity, skucount
OREDER BY `skuCount` desc
LIMIT 10000
```

You have to first get a result set with the counts for SKU and then join the tables.